# Редирект для сайта (301)

Tags: .htaccess

Подскажите как сделать редирект, с www,http и без сразу на https. В поиске отображается в данный момент все три. Как их все склеить в https?

Comment: Подобный вопрос много раз задавался на этом сайте. Вы пользовались [поиском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B.htaccess%5D+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82+www)? Какие способы попробовали? Что не получилось?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

или

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Пожалуйста. Если ответ правильный, то его желательно отметить как правильный. Это будет полезно другим участникам ресурса.